# problem with \textsc

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to use the `\textsc` command.
In the example below, the `\uppercase` works perfectly fine, but when using the `\textsc` the text is moved roughly 1cm to the right. I tried a `\raggedleft` or `\vpsace` command but it did not help.

```
\sectionfont{\vspace{0.5cm}\bfseries\fontsize{12pt}{0}\selectfont\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright \vspace{0.2cm}\mdseries\fontsize{12pt}{0}\selectfont\textsc}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a font *declaration*, so instead if `\textsc`, use `\scshape`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty,lipsum}

\sectionfont{\vspace{5mm}\bfseries\large\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\vspace{2mm}\mdseries\large\scshape}

\begin{document}

\sloppy % Just for this example
\section{A section}\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```